# ASP.NET Core 2.2.0 Identity Scaffolding still using bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am running the identity code generator

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc WebApplication1.Data.ApplicationDbContext --force
```

but the pages that are output are based on bootstrap 3 - what I've read suggests they should be bootstrap 4 (eg https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/712#issuecomment-420143440)

Is there something additional that I need to do to get BS4 based identity pages?

**Notes:**

I have ensured the tool is up to date:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
Tool 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '2.2.0').
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4) // specifying the boostrap4 here
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```